# Error initialising the React Native awsomeProject via the CLI

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get the basic react native app from https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup running via the CLI, but I am getting errors.  I have node, python2 and jdk8 installed.  I have all the Android Studio components installed as far as I can tell.  I've added the environment variables.

When I run `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` to initialise the project, I get green ticks next to `Downloading Template`, `Copying Template` and `Processing Template`, but a red cross next to `Installing dependencies`.  The error below that states `Error: command failed: npm install`.  And further down after some warnings it states `npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...anbul":"0.4.5","mocha'`

And in the initialised app folder there are no node modules.

Any idea how I get this working?

Comment: npm cache clean --force and try again

Comment: That fixed the error (thanks), but when running `npx react-native run-android` it came back with the error `Unrecognized command "run-android"`.

Comment: You shld run react-native run-android dont include npx

Comment: Please accept my answer as its working :)

Comment: `'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: try this npm install -g react-native-cli, but this error shld be a separate question as this is not related to ur issue

Comment: Awesome, that got it running fully on the emulator!  Thanks for your help, this has been killing me for days.

Comment: Glad it helped u 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the solution for this is to clear your cache :)

Please run the following command and retry:

> npm cache clean --force